# Bizzare identical incorrect results across different MWR2MM algorithms for RSA montgomery multiplication

Tags: c++, algorithm, cryptography, rsa, montgomery-multiplication

## Background

I'm trying to implement RSA 2048 in hardware (xilinx ZYNQ FPGA) using a variety of different Montgomery methods. I am implementing the algorithm using Xilinx HLS (essentially C++ code that is synthesized into hardware).

*Note: For the sake of this post, treat it just like a standard C++ implementation, except that I can have variables that act like bit-vectors up to 4096 bits wide, and access individual bits using `foo[bit]` or `foo.range(7,0)` syntax. I haven't yet parallelized it, so it should behave just like standard C++ code. Please don't be afraid and stop reading because I said the word FPGA and HLS. Just treat this one like C++ code.*

I've been able to get a working prototype that uses the standard square-and-multiply for modular exponentiation, and the standard radix-2 MM algorithm for the modular multiplication, however it takes up too much space on the FPGA and I need to use less resource-heavy algorithms.

To save space, I'm trying to implement the **Tenka-koc Scalable Multiple Word Radix 2 Montgomery Multiplication (MWR2MM)** proposed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/27j70szy98uve61/A%20Scalable%20Architecture%20for%20Modular%20Multiplication%20Based%20on%20Montgomery%27s%20Algorithm?dl=0). I've been struggling with it for a month but to no avail. However there is an interesting problem resulting out of my struggles that I cannot figure out.

## The Problem

**My issue is that MWR2MM does not return the correct answer when performing the Montgomery multiplication. However, I am beginning to think that it is not a coding error, and rather, that I am instead just misinterpreting something critical about the usage of the algorithm.**

There are multiple variations of the MWR2MM algorithm, with quite differing implementations, and I've tried to implement many of them. I currently have 4 different implementations of MWR2MM coded up, all based on modifications to the algorithm put forth in a number of papers. **What makes me think that my implementations are actually correct, is that all of these varying versions of the algorithm are returning the same INCORRECT answer!** I don't think this is coincidence, but I also don't think the published algorithms are wrong....Therefore, I posit that something more nefarious is actually going on, and my algorithm implementations are correct.

## Example 1

For example, take the original proposed MWR2MM put forth in tenca-koc's paper, which we refer to as MWR2MM_CSA because the algorithm's addition operations all use a carry-save adder (CSA) when implemented in hardware.

- S is the partial sum
- M is the modulus
- Y is the multiplicand
- X is the multiplier and x_i (subscript) is a single bit (e.g. X = (x_n,...,x_1,x_0).
- The superscript are the words vectors ( e.g. M = (0,M^{e-1},...,M^1,M^0)
- (A,B) is the concatenation of two bit vectors.
- m is the operands width
- w is the width of choosen words
- e is the number of w-bit words required to complete the vectors, (e.g. e = ceil((m+1)/w) )

[image]

My implementation of this algorithm uses the following parameters:

- `MWR2MM_m = 2048 (operand size, m from above)`
- `MWR2MM_w = 8 (word size, w from above)`
- `MWR2MM_e = ceil( (e+1)/w ) = 257 (number of words + 1 per operand, e from above)`
- `ap_uint<NUM_BITS>` is how you declare a bit vector in HLS

My code:

```
void mwr2mm_csa( ap_uint<MWR2MM_m> X,
                 ap_uint<MWR2MM_w> Y[MWR2MM_e+1],
                 ap_uint<MWR2MM_w> M[MWR2MM_e+1],
                 ap_uint<MWR2MM_m> *out)
{
    // Declare and zero partial sum S
    ap_uint<MWR2MM_w> S[MWR2MM_e] = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<MWR2MM_e; i++)
        S[i] = 0;

    // Two Carry bits
    ap_uint<1> Ca=0, Cb=0;

    for (int i=0; i<MWR2MM_m; i++)
    {
        (Ca,S[0]) = X[i]*Y[0] + S[0]; // this is how HLS concatenates vectors, just like in the paper!
        if (S[0][0] == 1) // if the 0th bit of the 0th word is 1
        {
            (Cb,S[0]) = S[0] + M[0];
            for (int j=1; j<=MWR2MM_e; j++)
            {   
                (Ca, S[j]) = Ca + X[i]*Y[j] + S[j];
                (Cb, S[j]) = Cb + M[j] + S[j];
                S[j-1] = ( S[j][0], S[j-1].range(MWR2MM_w-1,1) );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j=1; j<=MWR2MM_e; j++)
            {
                (Ca, S[j]) = Ca + X[i]*Y[j] + S[j];
                S[j-1] = ( S[j][0], S[j-1].range(MWR2MM_w-1,1) );
            }
        }
    }

    // copy the result to the output pointer
    for (int i=0; i<MWR2MM_e-1; i++)
        out->range(MWR2MM_w*i+(MWR2MM_w-1), MWR2MM_w*i) = S[i].to_uchar();
}
```

Now, it is my understanding that (quoting from the paper above)

> the Montgomery Multiplication (MM) algorithm on two integers X and Y ,
>   with required parameters for n bits of precision, will result in the
>   number MM(X,Y,M) = X*Y*(2^-n) (modulo m), where r=2^n and M is an
>   integer in the range (2^(n-1), 2^(n)) such that gcd(r,M)=1. Since
>   r=2^n , it is sufficient that the modulus M be an odd integer.

Therefore, we should expect the following results (verified w/ software library):

```
X = 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
Y = 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
M = 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
MM(X,Y,M) = 0x444682CC199679928F5971191ACCB8EAA5C76CF743E54FC28FD8DCFF57BD198677A26A5C1A6254810A91049FA85CBE3EDDFDCDF12ED3FBB204DE249C389CDEE3FA6DB65441AFE03F1148660EA0E756E038891CEF098F2A009FB443685202FAC40D8FE7B82A1F643020EA31F5A8F4B253AD2F30028C59F1E2DCF3902BBC48E73ECA7BDC22BB92E8A70BC535584BF644CAF24EF39A1899F18C05937446AACC5C64762AFAD2B73EEDF3AA96C9A4CFF836A551A26AED46279328EDD4B9BBBC182B9E408640D058926882B3A0FAA043F726EF96E07B7960D586E2648534EB15C23FE152D0D088F1742E023715E3ABAEC8128B51CC86E8BC207D69F1E6BA7067D44429
```

But instead, my algorithm returns

```
MWR2MM_csa(X,Y,M) = 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
```

## Example 2

Ok, so maybe that implementation was wrong. Lets try another modified version, the MWR2MM_CPA algorithm (named for the carry-propogate adders used in hardware):
[image]

And my implementation of MWR2MM_CSA:

```
void mwr2mm_cpa(rsaSize_t X, rsaSize_t Yin, rsaSize_t Min, rsaSize_t* out)
{
// extend operands to 2 extra words longer
ap_uint<MWR2MM_m+2*MWR2MM_w> Y = Yin; 
ap_uint<MWR2MM_m+2*MWR2MM_w> M = Min;
ap_uint<MWR2MM_m+2*MWR2MM_w> S = 0;

ap_uint<2> C = 0;
bit_t qi = 0;

// unlike the previous example, we store the concatenations in a temporary variable
ap_uint<10> temp_concat=0; 

for (int i=0; i<MWR2MM_m; i++)
{
    qi = (X[i]*Y[0]) xor S[0];

    // C gets top two bits of temp_concat, j'th word of S gets bottom 8 bits of temp_concat
    temp_concat = X[i]*Y.range(MWR2MM_w-1,0) + qi*M.range(MWR2MM_w-1,0) + S.range(MWR2MM_w-1,0);
    C = temp_concat.range(9,8);
    S.range(MWR2MM_w-1,0) = temp_concat.range(7,0);

    for (int j=1; j<=MWR2MM_e; j++)
    {
        temp_concat = C + X[i]*Y.range(MWR2MM_w*j+(MWR2MM_w-1), MWR2MM_w*j) + qi*M.range(MWR2MM_w*j+(MWR2MM_w-1), MWR2MM_w*j) + S.range(MWR2MM_w*j+(MWR2MM_w-1), MWR2MM_w*j);
        C = temp_concat.range(9,8);
        S.range(MWR2MM_w*j+(MWR2MM_w-1), MWR2MM_w*j) = temp_concat.range(7,0);

        S.range(MWR2MM_w*(j-1)+(MWR2MM_w-1), MWR2MM_w*(j-1)) = (S.bit(MWR2MM_w*j), S.range( MWR2MM_w*(j-1)+(MWR2MM_w-1), MWR2MM_w*(j-1)+1));
    }
    S.range(S.length()-1, S.length()-MWR2MM_w) = 0;
    C=0;
}

*out = S;
```

}

When run with the same X,Y and M, this too returns the exact same incorrect result as MWR2MM_CSA, despite different bit-level operations.

```
MWR2MM_cpa(X,Y,M) = 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
```

For brevity, I will spare you the two other algorithms that also return the same incorrect result. I should note that both of these algorithms work correctly when used with a 4-bit operand size and 2-bit word size. However any other operand size/word size combinations are incorrect, but have the same incorrect result for all four differing bit-level implementations.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why all four algorithms return the same incorrect result. My code in the first example literally is word-for-word identical to the algorithm put forth in the tenca-koc paper!

Am I incorrect at assuming that the MWR2MM algorithm should return the same result (in the montgomery domain) as the standard radix-2 MM algorithm? They have the same radix, so the results should be identical regardless of word-size. Should I not able to interchange these algorithms with each other?

sorry for the lengthy post, but I want to be very precise and coherent in explaining what the issue is. **I am not asking for help debugging my code**, but rather trying to figure out whether I am misunderstanding an underlying feature of the montgomery multiplication algorithms. Also curious why different implementations are giving the same **WRONG** result.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your value for e is correct?  With 257 word widths of 4, this gives a total of 257*4=1028 bits which is less than 2048.

Comment: whoops, typo sorry. word width should be 8. Correcting in OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your algorithm actually returns:

```
0x116c27cbc37...
  ^
```

which is greater than M.  If you subtract M from this you get the expected answer:

Both algorithms return a value in the range 0 to 2*M, so if the answer is greater or equal to M, you need a final subtraction stage.

In other words, if you test your algorithm with randomly chosen X and Y you should find that half of the time it gives the correct answer.

From section 2 of the paper:

> Thus only one conditional subtraction is necessary to bring S[n] to the required range 0 ≤ S[n] < M. 
>   This subtraction will be omitted in the subsequent discussion since it is independent of the specific algorithm and architecture and can be treated as a part of post processing.

Comment: *facepalm*. I have been working on this for so long, and read that paper so many times....I don't know how I missed that. The standard single-word radix-2 algorithm involves the final subtraction of the modulus as well, but for some reason I thought that the multiple-word version had that baked into the algorithm. Thank you, thank you, thank you Peter, for pointing out that oversight. It all works perfectly now!